# Declare and fill in the an array with the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array using a for loop in JavaScript. I want my array to be consisted of 10 variables or more (var kaunt1, var kaunt2, etc...) which will be actually numbers from div tags.

I tried this code below, but it isn't working??? Am I missing something?

```
var arr = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        var kaunt[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("A"+i).innerHTML, 10);
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: You will never define the first item in the array. Arrays are 0-indexed in JavaScript. Your loop should be `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: it would be useful if you posted some markup of the divs to disambiguate what exactly you want in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other's beat me I think, but this should do it...

```
var kaunt = new Array();
for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    kaunt[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById("A"+i).innerHTML, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`var kaunt[i] = ...` isn't how you add an index to an array, that's a syntax error.

Just use `kaunt[i] = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `arr`, but using `kaunt`? Not sure what that's about, but you should normalize that if they're meant to be the same thing.

Anyway, use `kaunt.push(parseInt(document.getElementById("A"+i).innerHTML, 10));` (no `var`) inside your `for`.

Comment: Yes, that will shift the array eleents to the left though: kaunt[0] will contain A1.

Comment: @MauricePerry `kaunt[0]` being `undefined` is more useful?

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes, as I would say it should. Use logic to access it, or use an object. Messing with array indexes is a no no. In my world, anyhow.

Comment: Not at all, I just thought it should be mentionned

Comment: I totally agree that that's the way it should be

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the var in front of kaunt[i].

```
kaunt[i] = ....
```